# how to rename a tag with ActsAsTaggableOn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

In a rails 3 application , I'm using ActsAsTaggableOn to tag my articles.

I'd like to be able to rename tags, with an edit view.

i've made a *tags_controller.rb* and a *view/tags/edit.html.haml*.
In tags_controller.rb

```
def edit
  @tag =  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.find(params[:id])
end
```

In view/tags/edit.html.haml

```
= form_for(@tag, :html => {:multipart => true})  do |f|
```

gives me an error : undefined method `**acts_as_taggable_on_tag_path**' for #<#:0x007fdd7404ee40>

how can I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never try this gem but i think it can help you to do it easily : https://github.com/kryzhovnik/rails_admin_tag_list